# Replacing innerHtml instead of append

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in which first row is a label and drodown for selecting number of spaces.
based on the number selected that much number of rows and inside each row  another table with input fields will come. everithing is ok in first time.but when i reselect the number from dropdown the number of rows append to the previous one. i want to replace the previous inner tables. how to do this.

**this is my html code**

```
<table  border="1" style="border-style:dotted" width="100%" id="table_booking">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label > Number Of Spaces</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="dropdown" class="" name="spaces" onchange="addForm(this.value)">
                <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <table  border="1" style="background-color:gray" width="100%" id="table_form">
    </table>
</table>
```

**this is the script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addForm(space)
    { var val=space;
        document.getElementById('dropdown').value =val;
        var doc=document.getElementById('table_booking');
        for(var i=0;i<val;i++)
            doc.innerHTML += '<tr><td><table width="100%" id="table_form"><tr><td><form><label>Name </label><input type="text"></form></td></tr></table></td></tr>';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but that is not even close to valid html.  You shouldn't really be using tables for laying out your content, and regardless of that fact, you should not have a table directly inside another table element, it should be in a tr / td combo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before appending, just flush the existing innerHTML like

```
doc.innerHTML = '';
```

Then append it,

```
for(var i=0;i<val;i++)
  doc.innerHTML += '<tr><td><table width="100%" id="table_form"><tr><td><form><label>Name </label><input type="text"></form></td></tr></table></td></tr>';
```

---

**Updates:** Looking through your comments in other answers, I have devised the following approach,

```
 function addForm(space) {
     var val = space;
     var doc = document.getElementById('table_booking').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

// Remove nodes whenever we append new nodes to the tbody (RESET)

     if (doc.getElementsByTagName('tr').length > 1) {
         var len = doc.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
         for (i = (len - 1); i >= 1; i--) {
             doc.getElementsByTagName('tr')[i].remove();
         }
     }

// Based on the value selected, new rows will be appended to the tbody

     for (var i = 1; i <= val; i++) {
         t = doc;
         r = t.insertRow(i);
         c = r.insertCell(0);
         c.innerHTML = "<form><label>Name </label><input type='text'></form>";
         doc.appendChild(r);
     }
 }
```

### [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/amsZ3/)